# How to return to main activity after being three activities down?

Tags: android

My app has four activities; MainActivity, ListActivity1 (L1) , ListActivity2 (L2), ListActivity3 (L3). From Main, the user goes down to L1 by clicking a button. After selecting an item in L1, user comes to L2 and then L3 after selecting an item in L2. In L3, when selecting an item a Yes/No-toast is launched. If user selects "No", user stays on L3. If user selects "Yes", user returns way back to Main.

Here's the question: If the user selects "yes" taking him to Main and pressing Back button, he returns to L3. What I want is that if the user has walked down to L3, selected yes and returned to Main, pressing Back should take him to Home screen. I.e. I want to delete the "back trace" to L3.

How do I accomplish this?

(Main and the ListActivities starts the new activity with `startActivity(new Intent(foo, Bar.class))`)

Comment: If the user selects yes on L3, should they be able to press back to go to L2 and then back again to go to L1? Or do L1 and L2 not matter after you get to L3?

Comment: L1 and L2 only matter if "no" is selected on L3. If "Yes" is selected, discard all "back tracing" to L3, L2 and L1. I'm not sure this makes sense, but I hope it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this when yes is selected:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                    
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the activity stack so L1, L2, and L3 are removed and the existing MainActivity is started with the new intent.

Comment: I think that call to finish is unnecessary.  If the activity is a child activity, it will be finished by the OS because of the clear top flag.

Comment: If he is in a dialog listener, keeping a reference of the activity around just to do an unnecessary call to finish on it is a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when you start L2 and L3, you start it with startAcitiv

> startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

You can define a result code in your L1 and L2 activity. In L3, when the user click "Yes", before finishing the Activity, you call

> setResult(USER_CLICKED_YES);

You can define USER_CLICKED_YES as an integer that L2 knows.

In L2, you can implement onActivityResult() and in the method, you check if the result of L3 whether or not it's USER_CLICKED_YEs, if it is, you finish L2, if not, do nothing.

This way, you build a "finishing activity chain" so that Activities can finish itself until it reaches the activity that you doesn't want to finish.

Comment: This way is not the optimal solution for the OP's case, but might be useful to someone else.  The other answer is a better way to achieve clearing the stack.  The user would see multiple activity closing animations if you implemented it this way, so I suggest that you don't.